# Facebook log in with Parse SDK (iOS 9, Xcode 7.1, Swift 2.1)

Tags: parse-platform, ios9, swift2, xcode7.1

I've been trying to implement Facebook log in. As the titles says, I'm using **Xcode 7.1**, **Swift 2.1**, **iOS 9.1**, **Parse SDK** (ParseFacebookUtilsV4).

I have read Parse [doc](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users) and Facebook [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#xcode), and already setup the **.plis** according to iOS 9 requirements.

The thing is, when the app runs and calls `logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions:, block:)`, I'm getting:

***-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"***

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add this to the plist as well. Not sure if it was documented on the Facebook docs.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>`enter code here`
</array>
```

Each item is for a different part of Facebook SDKs so you might only need to add the fbauth2 one. The others are there in case you need them.

Comment: Facebook doc is mentioning that, actually, Facebook suggests different lists of arrays and/or strings based on sdk version used for, but is doesn't work.